# Choice command not differing

Tags: batch-file

I have written the following code

```
choice /m "Do you want to add another profile" 
if errorlevel 1 set /p profile_name1=Enter one of the above profile names:
```

However it always runs "Enter one of the above profile names:" even though I pressed no. What did i do wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean: %errorlevel% ?, also please edit your post to include the code formatting so we can read it better

Comment: Jonno, i tried to the first time it just does what it does above!!!! This looks better I am sorry :
choice /m "Do you want to add another profile" 
if errorlevel 1 set /p profile_name1=Enter one of the above profile names:

And NO i dont mean %errorlevel%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give instructions for each outcome.
E.g.:

```
choice /m "Do you want to add another profile"
if errorlevel 2 goto :doOtherStuff
if errorlevel 1 set /p profile_name1=Enter one of the above profile names: 
:doOtherStuff
```

Also note that the order is important, you must list the errorlevels in descending order (2 then 1).

Answer (score 0):

First, /m is not a valid argument you can pass to choice.  Try removing that, it might be confusing choice.

Also: 
`IF ERRORLEVEL` returns TRUE if the return code was equal to *or higher* than the specified errorlevel.  Try checking every possible return value (in your case, both yes and no)

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 SET ANS="No"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET ANS="Yes"
```

and use the value of ANSwer in the rest of your batch file.

Comment: Wrong, according to the result of choice /?: 

 /M    text          Specifies the message to be displayed before
                     the prompt. If not specified, the utility
                     displays only a prompt.

Comment: I think you are wrong.  The only documented switches I can find are /C, /N/ S/ & /T  - do you have a reference?  I'd like to know.

Comment: I have a basic windows XP install - I don't even have choice on my machine, so I only have online documentation to go by as far as that goes, but the real problem is the errorlevel line anyways.

Comment: @Jan: in newer versions of Windows, the choice command has different switches, including /M. For Win 7 for example, you get: `CHOICE [/C choices] [/N] [/CS] [/T timeout /D choice] [/M text]`